# window.location with search query yields nxdomain

Tags: javascript, html, networking, dns, window.location

I have the following problem. My website has an  element, with onclick="window.location = 'sd.domain.tld?search=value'" targeting another server. When some users click on it, they get NXDOMAIN instead of being redirected to the other webside. However, when I remove the search query from the location string, everything works fine for everyone. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Google did not provide any answers...

Comment: Surely that should be `onclick="window.location = 'http://sd.domain.tld?search=value'"`... (or `https`, of course).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. Sorry for misinforming you - I specified the protocol in both cases. I guess it is worth mentioning, that the protocol is https on both servers. But thanks for the reply anyway. At least it is good to know that the post is not ignored :)